# Ingesting JSON into elasticsearch with python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, data-ingestion

I am just starting to use Elasticsearch, but as I have no experience with json files, I am having difficulty in indexing my data. Using the following code, the data is indexed in elastic, however the fields appear empty. Could you please tell me how to index the data correctly? I guess my error comes from the formatting of my json file.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

client = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://localhost:9200"])
docs = []
docs.append({"activite":{"0":"94.99Z","1":"93.12Z","2":"88.99B","3":"90.01Z","4":"88.91A"},"top_activites":{"0":195,"1":193,"2":111,"3":55,"4":36}})

helpers.bulk(client, docs, index="index_for_python_test")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example help you:

```
datas = []
datas.append({"activite": {"0": "94.99Z", "1": "93.12Z", "2": "88.99B", "3": "90.01Z", "4": "88.91A"},
              "top_activites": {"0": 195, "1": 193, "2": 111, "3": 55, "4": 36}})

datas.append({"activite": {"0": "94.99Z"}, "top_activites": {"0": 195}})

operations = []
for data in datas:
    action = {"index": {"_index": "index_for_python_test"}}
    doc = json.dumps(data)
    operations.append(action)
    operations.append(doc)

response = get_client_es().bulk(index="index_for_python_test", body=operations)
print(response)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Following your example, I still have in elastic "activite" as 5 different fields instead of one.

Comment: you have a object "activite" with 5 properties inside. How do you imagine being indexed?